# How to get the index of selected item in KendoMobileListView

Tags: kendo-ui

I want to know how I can get the index of selected Item in Kendo mobile ListView. This is my code

```
function loadInformation(){
$('#Template').kendoMobileListView({        
    dataSource: Info,
    template: '<table  style="width: 100%"><tr><td><p>${a = (typeof data.ServiceLocationCompanyName !== "undefined") ? data.ServiceLocationCompanyName : data.LastName + ", " + data.FirstName}</td><td style="width: 84px"><img src=${data.Icon} /></td></tr></table>',

    // Added this event to capture the index of selected Item but was unsuccessful
    click: function(){
    var index = this.select().index(),
    console.log(index);        
    }
});
```

When I run this, it gives me an error saying

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'select'
```

What do I need to do here ? How can I get the index of the selected item ? cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a try with this:

```
function loadInformation(){
    $('#Template').kendoMobileListView({        
        dataSource: Info,
        template: '<table  style="width: 100%"><tr><td><p>${a = (typeof data.ServiceLocationCompanyName !== "undefined") ? data.ServiceLocationCompanyName : data.LastName + ", " + data.FirstName}</td><td style="width: 84px"><img src=${data.Icon} /></td></tr></table>',

        // Added this event to capture the index of selected Item but was unsuccessful
        click: function(e){
           var index = $(e.item).index();
           var text = $(e.item).text();
           console.log('selected item contains text: ',text,' and its index is: ',index);        
        }
    });
}
```